# How do I create a profile when starting IPython via python -m IPython?

Tags: ipython

Which command is the equivalent of

```
ipython profile create
```

when I normally start ipython via

```
python -m IPython
```

(i.e. I did not install IPython, just unzipped it and adapted PATH and PYTHONPATH)?

Comment: Did you try `python -m IPython profile create`?

Comment: @ThomasK: thanks, this seems to work. Also `python -m IPython config -h` now gives me output.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It's pretty bad form to downvote a new user for a valid question without even leaving a comment.

Comment: IIRC, I got some message or feedback stating that the question did not show that I had put research effort into it. Don't remember if that message was generated automatically or by a human.